Extra 0x00 sent at end of RS485 message
I am currently trying to use an arduino to send an RS485 via an SP3078EEN RS485 transciever. I have my arduino code set the DE pin high, wait 1ms, then write and flush a data buffer to the serial which is connected to the DI pin of the transciever. Post-this it sets the DE pin low again. This is almost all working as intended except for the fact that I am getting an extra 0x00 byte after my data as read by my oscilloscope and PC (measured via an RS485 to USB converter).
Below I have the important portion of my code as well as the oscilloscope measurements of Di (Driver Input), A (RS485 Positive Output) and DE (Driver Enable). I also have provided a simplified schematic of my circuit. The only thing I can see that might be the cause of this is the seemingly capacitive discharge on the "A" signal which occurs when I switch DE from high to low. I don't know why this is happening or how to fix it. I have tried putting pullup / pulldown resistors on RO, RE and DI to no avail. I have also tried increasing the pre-write delay and also adding a post-write delay, also to no avail.
If anyone can help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.
Oscilloscope

Code:
void setup() {
    Serial0.begin(19200, SERIAL_8E1);
    Serial1.begin(19200, SERIAL_8E1);
}

void loop() {

    // Setting the buffer to a static value for debugging purposes
    byte buffer1 = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x44, 0x09 };

    // Set the DE_1 pin high to enable writing to the RS485 bus
    digitalWriteFast(DE_1_PIN, HIGH);

    delay(1);

    // Write the buffer to the RS485 bus
    Serial1.write(buffer1, 8); 
    Serial1.flush();
    
    // Disable writing
    digitalWriteFast(DE_1_PIN, LOW);

    delay(1000);
}



Super-Simplified Schematic


Oops, apologies it looks like I changed the buffer between when I copied the code and took the oscilloscope images. Rest assured I am getting all the correct values as per the code, except for the extra 0x00 at the end. I have edited the question to reflect the correct values.

We had the same issue at my company, and it turned out (as Tom wrote in his answer) to be an issue with the fail-safe biasing of the chip not working properly. Never really understood why it didn't though. But we played it safe and included external fail-safe biasing, which solved it.
I'd recommend to take a look at the following resources: https://advantech-bb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/RS-422-RS-485-eBook.pdf
https://www.renesas.com/en/document/apn/an1986-external-fail-safe-biasing-rs-485-networks

Thanks for the resource @LarsPetersson!

Why do you flush the buffer before disabling DE?

@MrGerber Referring to the Arduino website, to wait for the outgoing serial data transmission to complete. The write will return before that as it is asynchronous and returns immediately and data buffer transfers happen in the background using interrupts.

The extra 0x0 is not being sent by the ATTiny. Rather it is due to the RS485 bus apparently idling low rather than idling high.
As a result when the DE pin goes low, it causes the bus to go from high to low which is seen as a start bit. You will then decode a NULL (0x0) value but with a framing error because there is a missing stop bit.
According the the SP3078E datasheet, it should have fail-safe biasing such that when not driven the receiver idles high. I'm not sure why this is not happening. Perhaps you have another device connected with reversed polarity (A-B swapped)? or the scope probe is providing enough loading to overcome the bias (does probing the B pin instead help)?
You could try adding your own fail-safe biasing. This consists of a pair of kOhm sized resistors (e.g. 2.2kOhm or 4.7kOhm), one pulling the B line to +5V, and the other pulling the A line to GND. Combined with the 120R termination, this will produce about ~65-130mV between A-B which should comfortably be detected as a '1' when the bus is floating.

Thanks heaps! I'm not sure why the failsafe of the chip isn't working as intended, but I have added a 4.7k bia resistor between A and +5V and between B and GND and this has worked! I didn't have any 2.2k's on me but I will try with those as soon as I can. This definately seemed to be the problem and I have it working now with the added biasing.

@PatrickVoorhoeve 4.7k is fine, IIRC I think I had 2.2k lying around last time I had this issue.

I wouldn't trust that fail-safe. It's pretty much standard practice to have an external pull-up on the RO pin for when the MCU is (re)booting. Then you shouldn't need no pull resistors on the other side towards the bus.

@Lundin as he explains, the issue is not specifically the ATTiny receiving the extra null, so an RO pull-up wont make a difference (he tried that). He has a USB-RS485 adapter that is receiving the extra NULL character, as is the oscilloscope decoding. This is because the RS-485 bus when the DE pin goes low is floating to GND rather than remaining properly (fail-safe!) biased. As such every connected device will start to receive an extra packet because the lines have shifted to the point where they trigger a start bit.

In addition to the answer by Tom, on the software side you must absolutely handle overrun & framing errors - this is mandatory for every UART driver. Overrun meaning data was received before the MCU had cleared the previous Rx flag, framing meaning that the incoming data doesn't fit in the standard frame format (due to EMI, wrong baudrate, bad clock etc etc).
Lack of error handling appears to be the root of the problem: you seem to be relying on some library which either does not do it or wasn't told to do it.
At the very least clear these flags as part of the RX procedure and discard data when they are present. Otherwise the end result turns into "brittleware" that stops working as soon as someone sneezes near the serial cable...

I think you are correct - people should handle those errors. Unfortunately, this project uses the Arduino framework, and such hobbyist toys have UART drivers that handle errors by not handling them. So this does not answer the question really.

In many cases, unless a library can record and report such errors "in sequence"--something I seldom see in serial libraries--there may not be any good way of handling them, especially if packets have either an 0xFF byte or a minimum of nine marking bits between them, and transmission of a new packet may be underway by the time application code has processed all of the preceding bytes and packets are guarded by a CRC-16 or CRC-32.

@Justme Since this is an engineering site we are obliged to point out best practices and industry standards. It does answer the question even if the OP is using a tool and library which is unsuitable for electrical engineering or other professional use. If they just want "broken toy" support then there's https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ for that.

@supercat Quite often when the UART isn't a critical bus in the system (it really shouldn't be in the year 2024) but just some debug dump or similar, it is not uncommon to just poll all the status flags before reading rx and then just ignore the data when there's an error flag set. With DMA and similar it becomes trickier. Personally I stopped using UART-like buses all together some 10+ years ago in favour for CAN, even when I just do debug dumps or bootloaders. Good riddance.

@Lundin Handling overrun or framing errors is not in any way mandatory, you don't need to do it if you don't feel like it will be beneficial for random hobbyist project. If it were mandatory, the Arduino folks would already have to do it before anything works. Also what to do when such errors happen depend on application. Sure, it is just nice to know a byte has framing error on reception or you have an overrun error so byte or more is lost, can can act accordingly when it matters. But the OP has a hardware problem not solved by checking framing errors because the hardware causes them.

Hey, I think y'all are absolutely correct and I thank you for the advice. In this case it was absolutely the hardware problem which as causing the additional byte to be interpreted by my RS485 USB converter. The code as a whole actually does include many of the afformentioned error checking in it, and I plan to add more now that this issue is solved; (using MODBUS, so CRC16, specific framing, etc etc...). I trimmed out  basically all of the code not related exactly to the problem to make it easier to solve.

I had the same issue using the MAX3485E. I ended up using 1kohm resistors between A and +3.3V and between B and GND. I am using a ESP32 for requesting Modbus values from a VFD.
#define RS485 Serial1  // Define Serial1 as RS485
byte VFD_GET_Freq[8] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x27, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 };
const int Get_Respose_Buffer_Size = 7;
int VFD_Frequency;
unsigned int RS485DelayTime = 5;   // RS485 Delay Time
unsigned int RS485Timeout = 1000;  // RS485 Timeout Time
int RTS = 12; // Digital output pin 12 RTS used for #RE / DE on the MAX3485E

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Debug Serial monitor
  RS485.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1, RX1, TX1); // UART Serial for RS485 MAX3485E
  pinMode(RTS, OUTPUT); // UART Serial for RS485 MAX3485E
  digitalWrite(RTS, LOW); // Turn off the output RTS so we can receive the response
  uint16_t CRC = ModRTU_CRC(VFD_GET_Freq, sizeof(VFD_GET_Freq) - 2); // Get the CRC for the Modbus request
  VFD_GET_Freq[6] = CRC; // Set the CRC byte
  VFD_GET_Freq[7] = (CRC >> 8); // Set the CRC byte
}

void loop() {
  Modbus_GET(VFD_GET_Freq, sizeof(VFD_GET_Freq), VFD_Frequency); // Send Modbus request
  Serial.printf("Freq: %d\n", VFD_Frequency); // Serial print out the VFD_Frequency value
  delay(RS485DelayTime); // Delay between each request
}

void Modbus_GET(byte Modbus_Message[], int Message_Len, int &Frequency) {
  digitalWrite(RTS, HIGH); // Turn on output RTS
  delay(1); // A little delay for the output to turn on
  while (RS485.available() > 0) { RS485.read(); }  // Make sure RS485 UART buffer is empty
  RS485.write(Modbus_Message, Message_Len); // Send Modbus request
  RS485.flush(); // Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete
  digitalWrite(RTS, LOW); // Turn off the output RTS so we can receive the response
  byte Modbus_Response_Buffer[Get_Respose_Buffer_Size]; // Byte buffer for the response
  // Timely Response loop, if we don't get a response with in the RS485Timeout then we failed to get the data
  // Set the Frequency value to 0
  unsigned long start = millis();
  while (RS485.available() < Get_Respose_Buffer_Size) {
    if (millis() - start > RS485Timeout) {
      Frequency = 0;
      Serial.println("Failed GET Timely Repsonse"); // Debug purpose only
      return;
    }
  }
  // If we received the exprected response bytes then set the Frequency
  if (RS485.available() == Get_Respose_Buffer_Size) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < Get_Respose_Buffer_Size; i++) { Modbus_Response_Buffer[i] = RS485.read(); }
    Frequency = (Modbus_Response_Buffer[3] << 8) | Modbus_Response_Buffer[4];
    Serial.println("Sucess GET"); // Debug purpose only
    // Debug purpose only will print the Modbus_Response_Buffer in HEX
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(Modbus_Response_Buffer); i++) {Serial.print(" 0x");
      if (Modbus_Response_Buffer[i] < 0x10) Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(Modbus_Response_Buffer[i], HEX);
    }
    Serial.println(); // Debug purpose only
  } else {
    Frequency = 0;
    Serial.println("Failed GET Incorrect Bytes");// Debug purpose only
  }
}

uint16_t ModRTU_CRC(byte buf[], int len) {
  uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;
  for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
    crc ^= (uint16_t)buf[pos];      // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc
    for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--) {  // Loop over each bit
      if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) {    // If the LSB is set
        crc >>= 1;                  // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
        crc ^= 0xA001;
      } else        // Else LSB is not set
        crc >>= 1;  // Just shift right
    }
  }
  return crc;
}
```

